# cupy/numpy, replacing cupy.tile with as_strided

Tags: python, numpy, large-data, cupy, stride

I didn't think this would be as irritating as it has proven to be. I have the following `tile` call:

```
vertices = cp.tile(
    vertices, 
    (1, 1, chunk_size, 1), 
)
```

I found that, when I printed out the the strides with `chunk_size=5`, I found that before tiling it is:

```
vertices.strides=(72, 24, 24, 8)
```

and after tiling it is:

```
vertices.strides=(360, 120, 24, 8)
```

So, I thought "I just multiply the first two strides by `chunk_size`":

```
s = vertices.strides
vertices = cupy.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(
    vertices,
    shape=(
        vertices.shape[0],
        vertices.shape[1],
        vertices.shape[2] * chunk_size,
        vertices.shape[3]
    ),
    strides=(chunk_size*s[0], chunk_size*s[1], s[2], s[3])
)
```

This does not work at all. Can someone enlighten me about how I should actually go about this?

I found some other posts, but I couldn't decipher how to transfer what they were saying to my case.

Comment: tiling increases the size of the data buffer.  as_strided uses the original.

Comment: Got it. So I should use the original strides?

Comment: I don't think it can be done, at least not directly.  `as_strided` usually is used to add a dimension (or more).  You could try adding a `chunksize` dimension between 1 and 2, with strides of 0.  But you'll be limited in what can do with the 5d array - many actions will blow it up to the full tiled size.

Comment: Aw bummer. It doesn't seem like a complicated problem to create a repeated view into an array, but i guess there's more to it than I can appreciate. By the way, the `vertices_shape[2]` is 1, and I am just adding a `chunk_size` dimension. Right before this i expanded dimensions, but it sounds like i shouldn't have?

Comment: That would account for the repeated 24 in rhe strides.  With a size 1, that dimension can be broadcast.  Look at `broadcast_to`.